# Obfuscation of java scripts through packer.js

Tags: javascript, obfuscation

I have obfuscated my scripts through [dean edward packer](http://dean.edwards.name/packer/) and when my html contains frameset and frames the output is not displaying properly through Internet Explorer but the same works in Firefox.

This problem happens only when my html includes the obfuscated scripts.

hi,

Thanks for the response.I did try using JSLint to check for missing semicolons in java script but would not find any.And more if I use tables instead of frameset its working fine but my requirement is to use frameset.

Comment: Dean edward's script usually removes 'unnecessary' semicolons, and spaces, which in turn, if the script is not written properly, will fail the whole js.

Comment: ^ +1 That only happens on unclean code - also please be aware that it's absolutely possible to unpack the code again, it's not quite as readable as before then but it's definitely usable.

Answer (score 1):

First, if you haven't already, remove your scripts from the HTML and include them in a separately included file (let's call it script.js). Minifiers work best on pure javascript only.

Second, run your script.js file through [jslint](http://www.jslint.com/). It will help you find obvious script issues and typo's (such as [trailing commas](http://www.google.ca/search?q=ie%20trailing%20comma) which can break IE)

Third, use google's [closure compiler](http://closure-compiler.appspot.com/home) for minification. It will actually do obfuscation, but only very trivial obfuscation unless you follow the guidelines available [here](http://code.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/api-tutorial3.html%20http://code.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/api-tutorial3.html).

Comment: I'd rather use http://jshint.com/, because JSLint adds too much noise. JSHint is useful, while JSLint already complains although the script is valid.

Comment: Thanks for the response.I did try using JSLint to check for missing semicolons in java script but would not find any.And more if I use tables instead of frameset its working fine but my requirement is to use frameset.

Comment: I would help immensely if you could provide some sample code or a test page. If you can demonstrate the problem on [jsfiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.com), we might be able to offer more relevant suggestions. Otherwise, there is not much more that can be suggested and this should be closed.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using http://code.google.com/p/minify/ ? I appreciate it doesn't do obfuscation but at the same time does seem to be more robust than other minimizers :)